# angularjs: simple example - ng-class or ng-controller does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

pls, help me with next question

I try to implement conditional classes on div blocks using ng-class but have encountered next problem - "it is not working". Example seems to be very simple, I even do not know how else it can be described.

But one more idea - controller does not working instead of ng-class.....i do not know.

Here you can see my code pls, probably you will find smth wrong or give me an advice.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Zm0g4QfkqzTD3h4FWfcp?p=preview

```
demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

var controllers = {};


controllers.testCntr = function ($scope)
  {
  $scope.setClass = function()
    {
      alert('works');
      return True;
    }
  };
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <title></title>

<style>

.red
  {
    color:red;
  }

</style>



    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div ng-controller="testCntr">
      <span ng-class="{red: $scope.setClass()}">Test color</span>

      <div>{{$scope.setClass()}}</div>

    </div>


</body>


</html>
```

Thanks for your amendments.

Comment: Thanks, I have understood my mistakes, but two things is unclear -1) why I should use .controller() instead of controllers = {} .....may be some articles to read 2)if alert will be remaining in code (or added to setClass() function) - it will raise 5 times :), why 5??? It is expected behavior

Comment: OK. To be fair - last question (concerning "alert") I will ask in another post.

Answer (score 2):

Several problems here.

1. You can only add one controller at a time with `.controller()`
2. In your template, `$scope` is already the context, so don't include it in the HTML
3. `True` should be `true`
4. You are missing an `ng-app` directive
5. `angular.js` is not included properly
6. Your `scripts.js` is not included

Here's a working version of your Plunkr with the changes above:  http://plnkr.co/edit/ybDScjDrrIkH8tBNfIg1?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

To add the controller to your app you should do this

```
  demoApp.controller('testCntr', function ($scope) {
    $scope.setClass = function() {
      alert('works');
      return True;
    }
  })
```

Working Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/LPY94jPJdIJX4pr9K5FY?p=preview

Working Demo:

```js
demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);
demoApp.controller('testCntr', function ($scope) {
    $scope.setClass = function() {
      alert('works');
      return 33;
      return True;
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demoApp" <div="" ng-controller="testCntr">
      <span ng-class="{red: $scope.setClass()}">Test color</span>
      <div>{{setClass()}}</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function which is in the **scope** from the view, just call it like that :

```
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <span ng-class="{'red': setClass()}">Test color</span>
      <div>{{setClass()}}</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Here the [**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/iv01qJHU0MuM2TXHBoMH?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You should create an app.js services.js and controllers.js

Your controller should be moved to the controllers.js and look a little something like this.

```
demoApp.controller('testCntr',function ($scope){
  $scope.setClass = (function(){
    alert('works');
    return True;
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your **script.js** file should be

```
var app = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

app.controller('testCntr', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.setClass = function() {
    return true;
  };

}
]);
```

and **html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">

  <head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
          .red {
             color:red;
          }
   </style>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="testCntr">
    <span ng-class="{red: setClass()}">Test color</span>
  </body>

</html>
```

It may solve your problem

Plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ftx3M0aG9G8cJtyrn5wj?p=preview